# How to fix a button at the bottom of a mobile screen on a Wordpress template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I coded some CSS and HTML into the CSS and PHP parts of a Wordpress theme in order to display a button at the bottom center of mobile screens.
The button displays fine in the Troy tester ( http://troy.labs.daum.net/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcat-technologies.com%2Fprueba-sticky-button%2F&device=D850 ) but in mobiles, it shows completely out of the viewable screen.

My question is if the CSS is correct and Where I must place the HTML for the button.

I has three template parts: header, page and footer, and two CSS files, styles.css and responsive.css

I added a CSS declaration on the main style.css file to hide the button on screens larger then 768px wide (see below)

I added the CSS style at responsive.css to format the button

I added the HTML code at different places on either the header.php and footer.php template parts.

```
css at main CSS file
#myFixedButton {
display: none;
}

css at responsive.css

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#myFixedButton {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px -7px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px -7px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px -7px #000000;
    background-color: #ededed;
    background-image: url("/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/unite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 16px;
    -moz-border-radius: 64px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 64px;
    border-radius: 64px;
    border-width: 0px;
    width: 272px;
    height: 64px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
    margin: 0 0 0 -136px;
    left: 50%;
}
}

HTML code at header.php. This HTML is immediately after the <body> tag

    <body>

    <div id="contenedor">

    <button id="myFixedButton"><a href="/sumate-al-equipo/">
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/overlay-logo.png" alt="¡Sumate al equipo!"  width="272" height="64"/></a>
    </button>

    <!--header continues-->
    <!--page template-->
    <!--footer template-->

    </div>
    </body>
```

The expected result is a button at the bottom center of any mobile screen.
The actual result is the button located outside the initial view, far away right and down.

Comment: Working fine for me. But the HTML you've provided isn't valid and could be part of the problem.

Comment: Hi EternalHour, thanks, you mean the open div tags?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code, It's for some classes overwritten the styles. so, Change the `width: 960px` in the `logos-footer` and your problem solved:

```css
.logos-footer {
    background-image: url(images/logos-footer-960.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    height: 64px;
    width: 960px; // -> change it to fit-content or 100% or remove it
}
```

Comment: Thans for your suggestion, so far it solved the problem!!